# CSS border renders differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

CSS dotted border not showing on firefox when I use similar border width and element width. Looks like firefox adds some offset before the border. Any idea how to fix it?

Here is the example:

```html
  <h3>width: 90px (works fine)</h3>
  <div style="width: 90px; background: yellow">
     <div style="border-top: 20px dotted red"></div>
  </div>
  
  
  <h3>width: 20px (border not showing on firefox)</h3>
  <div style="width: 20px; background: yellow">
     <div style="border-top: 20px dotted red"></div>
  </div>
```

Firefox: [image]

Chrome: [image]

Comment: if you want to draw circles rely on better techniques (radial-gradient, box-shadow ,svg, etc) than the dotted border. It will never do what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif I need border as I'm making it for cross-platform email clients, and the size and border styles are variable.

Comment: If you double the width, the border then shows, and it looks as if it's 20px width. Maybe it  just needs extra space to display the border correctly

Answer (score 1):

Instead use radial-gradient :-

```
.circle-with-yellow {
   background-position: 0 0;
   background-size: 20px 20px;
   background-image: radial-gradient(red 50%, yellow 10%);
   height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution, but the background color/image won't solve my issue. Because some email clients (old outlook) don't support  CSS gradient and some other modern CSS properties.

Comment: Then you have to use svg.